# The task status in the windows task schedule

Tags: schedule

How do I set the task status to failed in the task schedule ?

(for example, if the batch file is scheduled in Windows and I want to set the task status to 'failed' if the batch file execute)

Comment: You need to give more detail, i.e. what are you trying to accomplish, can the steps be split in the task, etc.?

Comment: i have a bat file which has the script to monitor a file, if the file is there the script is success else failed.

Comment: The task schedule will go to execute this bat file. i want if the monitor is not there the task schedule execute faile, is that happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your batch file and use the following command to "raise an error" to task scheduler:

```
%comspec% /c exit 1
```

You can then let task scheduler handle the rest, i.e. send email, etc.

Comment: when i add the script "%comspec% /c exit 1" in the last line of my bat file,the task displayed success after invoke this file in the task schedulder .  why not failed?

Comment: Not possible.  If you run just that, then it will return "Fail" to task scheduler.  Running exit 0, returns success to the scheduler.  Most likely your script is exiting / returning before it gets to the end.  Try and add an "echo WHATEVER >> log.txt" to see if it gets to the end.